# Check for existence of data from two Dataframe's columns in List

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm searching for `difference` between columns in `DataFrame` and a data in `List`.

I'm doing it this way:

```py
# pickled_data => list of dics

pickled_names = [d['company'] for d in pickled_data] # get values from dictionary to list
diff = df[~df['company_name'].isin(pickled_names)]
```

which works fine, but I realized that I need to check not only for `company_name` but also for `place`, because there could be two companies with the same name.

`df` contains also column `place` as well as `pickled_data` contains `place` key in the dictionary.

I would like to be able to do something like this

```py
pickled_data = [(d['company'], d['place']) for d in pickled_data]

diff = df[~df['company_name', 'place'].isin(pickled_data)] # For two values in same row
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert values to `MultiIndex` by [`MultiIndex.from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html), then convert both columns too and compare:

```
pickled_data = [(d['company'], d['place']) for d in pickled_data]

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(pickled_data)

diff = df[~df.set_index(['company_name', 'place']).index.isin(mux)]
```

**Sample**:

```
data = {'company_name':['A1','A2','A2','A1','A1','A3'],
        'place':list('sdasas')}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    

pickled_data = [('A1','s'),('A2','d')]

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(pickled_data)

diff = df[~df.set_index(['company_name', 'place']).index.isin(mux)] 

print (diff)
  company_name place
2           A2     a
4           A1     a
5           A3     s
```

Comment: getting error `'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'`, should I remove the `to_numpy()`?

Comment: @MarcelKopera - Yop, I think yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can form a set of tuples from your `pickled_data` for faster lookup later, then using a list comprehension over `company_name` and `place` columns of the frame, we get a boolean list of whether they are in the frame or not. Then we use this to index into the frame:

```
comps_and_places = set((d["company"], d["place"]) for d in pickled_data)

not_in_list = [(c, p) not in comps_and_places
               for c, p in zip(df.company_name, df.place)]

diff = df[not_in_list]
```